# Java7 / WatchEvent - why is it not an enum?

Tags: java, java-7

How would you use the `WatchEvent<T>` class of Java7?

I mean:

```
for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
    final WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();

    /*
     * This key is registered only for ENTRY_CREATE events,
     * but an OVERFLOW event can occur regardless if events are
     * lost or discarded.
     */
    if (kind == OVERFLOW) {
        continue;
    }

    // Cast is safe because we registered a path instance.
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>)event;
    final Kind<Path> type = ev.kind();
    if (type == ENTRY_CREATE) {
        // Do something.
    } else if (type == ENTRY_DELETE) {
        // Do something.
    } else if (type == ENTRY_MODIFY) {
        // Do something.
    }
}
```

Seems to be a bit ugly (well, two `else if` statements might be still ok, but...).
Why didn't they use an enum to denote the event types?

Comment: I don't know, but I'm sure the developer(s) had their reasons. Voting to close this question..

Comment: You can switch on enums, I don't see a bad thing with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally there is a cast on the result of calling `context` rather than doing an unsafe cast on the whole `WatchEvent`.

The types of events is deliberately open-ended. Particular implementations can return their own kinds. Therefore, the type of `Kind` cannot be an enum, though enums are a good way of defining particular values.